# Non Zero Exit Code Error - Articulation Points - SPOJ Submerge

Tags: java, graph, runtime-error

I learned the Cut Vertices and Bridges algorithm today and immediately put them to test by solving a couple of basic problems on Spoj and Codechef. Both of the codes that I submitted on both graders give me the same Runtime Error - NZEC (Non Zero Exit Code)

One of the problems is [Submerging Islands](http://www.spoj.com/problems/SUBMERGE/) on SPOJ.

We need to print the number of  articulation points in a graph.
Here is my code for it:

[Submerging Islands](http://ideone.com/R3v8dX)

It seems to work for all possible inputs I can think of but gives the same NZEC Error. I have tried to debug my code for the past five hours but have failed. The memory used seems fine to me and I don't think there is any chance of any exception to occur. What is the reason for this NZEC Error for my code?

I tried to debug and test my  code for location of the bug and it seems to lie in the dfs function which is common to both codes. Here is the dfs function:

```
static void dfs (int u , boolean isRoot)
{
    int child=0;
    visited[u]=1;
    disc[u]=++time;
    low[u]=disc[u];
    int sz = map.get(u).size();
    for(int i=0;i<sz;i++)
    {
        int v = map.get(u).get(i);
        if(visited[v]!=1)
        {
            child++;
            parent[v]=u;
            dfs(v,false);
            // Check if the subtree rooted with v has a connection to one of the ancestors of u
            low[u]  = Math.min(low[u],low[v]);
            // u is an articulation point in following cases
            // (1) u is root of DFS tree and has two or more chilren.
            if (isRoot&& child>=2)
                ap[u]=1;
            // (2) If u is not root and low value of one of its child is more
            // than discovery value of u.
            if ( !isRoot && low[v] >= disc[u])
                ap[u]=1;
        }
        else if (v != parent[u])
            low[u]  = Math.min(low[u], disc[v]);
    }
}
```

What is the reason for the NZEC Error?

Comment: Why don't you try to run your program locally and see exactly which exception it produces?

Comment: I made some test cases but it seems to work fine for them . I dont have the test data for the SPOJ problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this problem using DFS ,i.e., after submerging a point how many groups of cities we can reach, initially all cities are connected so total number of groups  will be one, but if after submerging a point , any part of city disconnecting will lead into more  than one groups, and hence , we will increase the counter by 1. 
Repeat this iteration after submerging every point, to get the  result. This approach resulted in a TLE for me.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).